# What is a word for something being simultaneously known and permissible?

Tags: single-word-requests

Given the following sentence: "The issue is **known** and **we are okay with it**." As in, it is still recognized as an issue, but perhaps it's noncritical.

Is there a way to combine both those two cases into a sentence that follows "The issue is [new word]."?

Comment: The issue is not-a-bug-it's-a-feature. Does that count as one word? :-)

Comment: The issue is _tolerated_ or _accepted_.

Answer (score 1):

From light to heavy:
**noted**, **acknowledged**, **pending**, **moot**, **...a nonissue**, **unimportant**

Answer (score 1):

You may try ***[acknowledged](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/acknowledge)***.

> **acknowledge**
>   verb
>   1. to admit to be real or true; recognize the existence, truth, or fact of

It can be an adjective that applies to a noun.

> The issue is acknowledged. (lit. We know the issue exists and recognize its validity).

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***deferred***. The word *defer* has two meanings:

> - yield to another's wish or opinion
> - hold back to a later time
>
> <sub>[Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/defer)</sub>

But, ***deferred*** will generally mean that any action on the issue will be postponed or delayed.